# How to place shortcodes with Wordpress Widget Areas?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, shortcode

With regards to shortcodes for widgets, when I use a shortcode on a page and place it in specific areas (between content) the widget always seems to show after the content where the widget area is.

Is it possible to place shortcodes anywhere in the content and have it shown where it is instead of where the widget area is ?

This is a custom widget, I'm not looking for a plugin answer.

Comment: Please share any attempts/reference you have made to achieve the scenario you have described?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, but my thinking is that, I will need to get the page data on the template and do a replace on the widget shortcode with the widget data ? if this makes sense

Comment: it will be very nice if you try what you think, and you will know for yourself whether it works or not

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was some other way to do this that I'm not aware off, as I'm still new at building WordPress themes